# ¿Porque me muestra undefined en el otro select dependiente en Spring boot + bootstrap + JPA +MYSQL+JSP?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsp, spring-boot

Tengo un Problema me muestra los datos del otro select dependiente undefined

dejo el código

en Repository

```
public interface DepartamentoRepository extends JpaRepository<Departamento,Long>{


@Query("SELECT d.iddepartamento as iddepartamento, d.nomdepartamento as nomdepartamento FROM Departamento d where pais.idpais = :idPais")
    List<Departamento> findByPais(@Param("idPais")Long idPais);
```

en interface Service

```
public interface DepartamentoService {

    List<Departamento> departamentoLista();
    Optional<Departamento> getDepartamento(Long iddepartamento);
    Departamento agregarDepartamento(Departamento departamento);
    String eliminarDepartamento(Long iddepartamento);
    String actualizarDepartamento(Long iddepartamento); 

    List<Departamento> findByPais(Long idPais);

}
```

en la clase ServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class DepartamentoServiceImpl implements DepartamentoService {
    private PaisRepository paisRepository;  
    private DepartamentoRepository departamentoRepository;  

@Autowired
public DepartamentoServiceImpl(PaisRepository paisRepository, DepartamentoRepository departamentoRepository) {

        this.paisRepository = paisRepository;
        this.departamentoRepository = departamentoRepository;
    }


@Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<Departamento> findByPais(Long idPais) {

        return departamentoRepository.findByPais(idPais);
    }
}
```

en el Controller

private ClienteService clienteService;

```
private TipoClienteService tipoClienteService;


private PaisService paisService;
private DepartamentoService departamentoService;
private ProvinciaService provinciaService;
private DistritoService distritoService;

@Autowired
public ClienteController(ClienteService clienteService, TipoClienteService tipoClienteService,
        PaisService paisService, DepartamentoService departamentoService, ProvinciaService provinciaService,
        DistritoService distritoService) {

    this.clienteService = clienteService;
    this.tipoClienteService = tipoClienteService;
    this.paisService = paisService;
    this.departamentoService = departamentoService;
    this.provinciaService = provinciaService;
    this.distritoService = distritoService;
}



@GetMapping("/cliente")
public String clienteLista(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("clientes",clienteService.listaCliente());
    model.addAttribute("tipoclientes",tipoClienteService.tClienteLista());
    model.addAttribute("paises",paisService.paisLista());
    return "venta/cliente";
}

@RequestMapping(value="cargarPais/{idpais}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public String cargarPais(@PathVariable("idpais") Long idpais, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Gson gson=new Gson();
     response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    return gson.toJson(departamentoService.findByPais(idpais));
}
```

en el JS

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('.myForm14 #comboboxPais').on('change', function(){

    var idPais= $('.myForm14 select#comboboxPais option:selected').val();
        alert(idPais);
        $.getJSON({         

             ajax : 'true',

            url:'../venta/cargarPais/' + idPais ,            


            success: function(data,statusText){             

                 var data = $.parseJSON(data);

                var html= '<option value="">Seleccione Departamento</option>';  


                for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){

                    html += '<option value="' + data[i].iddepartamento + ' " >' +data[i].nomdepartamento + '</option>';
                }


                  alert(data);
                  html += '</option>';
                  $('.myForm14 select#comboboxDepartamento').html(html);


            },
             error: function(ob,errStr) {
                    alert('error');
                    console.log(ob,errStr);

                }
    });         

});
```

});

En JSP

```
<div class="myForm14">
  <form:form action="${path}/venta/cliente" method="post"
                modelAttribute="paises">

  <div class="form-group row">

    <label for="pais" class="control-label col-md-2">Pais</label>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <select id="comboboxPais" >
            <option value="-1">Seleccione Pais</option>
                <c:forEach items="${paises}" var="pais">
                    <option value="${pais.idpais}">${pais.nompais}</option>
                </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div>

   <label for="comboboxDepartamento" class="control-label col-md-2">Departamento</label>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    <select  id="comboboxDepartamento" >
        <option value="-1">Seleccione Departamento</option>
    </select>
  </div>
 </div>
</form:form>
</div>
```

Me muestra cuando coloco la siguiente url: 
http://localhost:9090/proyecto/venta/cargarPais/1

[[1,"Lima"],[3,"Ayacucho"]]

pero en la url: http://localhost:9090/proyecto/venta/clientes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el log de salida es:

```
 Written [[[1,"Lima"],[3,"Ayacucho"],[4,"Arequipa"]]] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter@5fc3ca2d]
```

Cuando selecciono país  del combo  me muestra el siguiente combo pero con datos unidifined departamento  por ejemplo si selecciono un país me tiene que enlazar sus departamentos correspondientes pero no me muestra nada espero que alguien de la comunidad me pueda apoyar en solucionar este problema. estoy investigando.

Comment: ya me salio pero tenia que crear un proyecto nuevo en la version 2.1.8 Release  con el mismo código si genera pero ya no utilizo el GSON

Answer (score 0):

Te falta marcar el parametro del metodo como parametro de la query con @Param tu Repository.

Seria algo asi:

```
@Query("SELECT d.iddepartamento as iddepartamento, d.nomdepartamento as nomdepartamento FROM Departamento d where pais.idpais = :idPais") 
List<Departamento> findByPais(@Param("idPais") Long idPais);
```

Comment: gracias pero no es la solución saludos

Comment: Podrias mostrar tu Controller?